# How to use for loop to join multiple dataframe?

Tags: r

recently I have a fixed dataframe and would like to join this dataframe to multiple dataframe. Below please see my example:

```
df1 <- data.frame (first_column  = c("key", "key"),
                  second_column = c("a", "a")
)

df2 <- data.frame (first_column  = c("key", "key"),
                   second_column = c("b", "b")
)

df3 <- data.frame (first_column  = c("key", "key"),
                   second_column = c("c", "c")
)

join <- data.frame (first_column  = c("key", "key"),
                   join_column = c("join", "join")
) 

#df1 df2 df3 are the dataframe that needed to by joined by df.join
```

I try to create a for loop to join it:

```
for (i in 1:length(df.list)) {
  df <- df.list[[i]]
  assign(paste(names(df.list[[i]])),"_joined"),left_join(df, join, by = c("first_column"= "first_column"))
}
```

However, I have encountered 2 problems:

1. I cannot create a variable name by using the name in for loop [i]
2. I cannot create 3 different dataframe by using this for loop.

Below please see the result that I want to get

```
> df1_joined
  first_column second_column join_column
1          key             a        join
2          key             a        join

> df2_joined
  first_column second_column join_column
1          key             b        join
2          key             b        join

> df3_joined
  first_column second_column join_column
1          key             c        join
2          key             c        join
```

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can put the dataframes in a list and join them using `lapply`.

```
list_df <- list(df1, df2, df3)
result <- lapply(list_df, function(x) 
                 merge(x, join, by = 'first_column', all.x = TRUE))
```

To get separate joined dataframes assign them the names and use `list2env`.

```
names(result) <- sprintf('df%d_joined', seq_along(result))
list2env(result, .GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `paste(names(df.list[[i]])),"_joined")` is getting the names of a single dataframe, which are the column names.

Just switch to `paste("df",i,"_joined")` should give you the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

We can also do this as

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
out <- mget(ls(pattern = '^df\\d+$')) %>%
        map(~ .x %>% 
                 left_join(join, by = 'first_column'))
```